# Send a reference to a variable instead of it's value

Tags: c#, variables, reference

I have a function that does a long task and I want to update a variable somewhere else occasionally with status updates. (If there is a better method for doing this, that's fine too) I'm writing a library and this code might be called several times at once so creating another variable in the same class that stores the variable isn't an option. Here is what my code might look like:

```
public static bool Count(int Progress, int CountToWhat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CountToWhat; i++) {
        Progress = CountToWhat / i; // This is how I'd like to update the value, but obviously this is wrong
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered not making this static? Then you could keep a variable in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature to:

```
public static bool Count(ref int Progress, int CountToWhat)
```

And when you call it, use the ref keyword before the variable that you pass in as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks, this was the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good way of providing updates to your callers.

Better you define one ore more events in your class library (like `OnError`, `OnProgress`, etc.). 
You can raise, for example, `OnProgress` when you want to notify progress in a certain operation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CountToWhat; i++) {
  OnProgress(CountToWhat / i);
  Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}
```

This is a much better way of doing it, especially when notifying from worker threads.

Comment: If static event handlers doesn't make much sense for your specific case, you could instead make the method take a callback, e.g. `public static bool Count(int Progress, int CountToWhat, Action<int> OnProgress)`.  That way it's locally-scoped instead of static.

Comment: @TimS.: Of course, callbacks are always a good alternative, even in non-static situations.

Comment: While I +1'd the "`ref`" answers because they will work, this is the **preferred** method to achieve this result.

Comment: @Nate: No, I can't +1 any `ref` answers. It would mean you have to poll somehow the variable from the calling thread. Ugly code...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll be sure to note this method in the future, but for now I just need something simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
int Progress = 0;
public static bool Count(ref int Progress, int CountToWhat)
{
  ....
}
```

Or

```
int Progress; //without init
public static bool Count(out int Progress, int CountToWhat)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by, *"the reference is used on class not on primitive type."*?  Additionally you *may* use out/ref, but it's not the only way.

Comment: if you test this method for example with Class1 as parameter, public void Test(Class1 value){...}; you don't need to add key words as ref or out,,,just that

Comment: There is still a purpose to using ref/out on classes, under certain circumstances.  Anyway, my point was that it's poorly phrased and isn't understandable as it's currently written.

Comment: that's made Servy and Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1):

A better way might be to pass an `Action<int>` delegate to be called to report progress:

```
public static bool Count(int CountToWhat, Action<int> reportProgress) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CountToWhat; i++) 
    {
        var progress = CountToWhat / i; 
        reportProgress(progress);
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    }
}
```

then you'd use it like:

```
Count(100, p => currentProgress = p);
```

You could also use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class to run your long running task, and utilize its [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.